# Combine two add actions into 1 php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

my problem is I have no clue about PHP. But I would like to combine the two following Actions into one.

Number 1

```
/* Add fee to specific product*/ 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_fees_on_ids'); 
function add_fees_on_ids() { 
   if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {return;} 
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_keys => $item ) { 
     if( in_array( $item['product_id'], fee_ids() )) { 
     WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Additional Charge'), 10); 
     } 
   } 
} 
function fee_ids() { 
   return array( 652,645,625 ); 
}
```

Number 2

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function() {
if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
return;
}
$percentage = 0.04;
$percentage_fee = (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()) * $percentage;
 WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Tax', 'txtdomain'), $percentage_fee);
});
```

As a result, I would like to have a percentage fee for just some product IDs (in the example 652,645,625). The Additional Charge can be deleted. I did not take it out, because I have no idea how...

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Add fee to specific product */
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_fees_on_ids');

function add_fees_on_ids() {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    $has_specifc_product = false;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_keys => $item) {
        if (in_array($item['product_id'], fee_ids())) {
            $has_specifc_product = true;
        }
    }
    if ($has_specifc_product) {
        $percentage = 0.04;
        $percentage_fee = (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()) * $percentage;
        WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Tax', 'woocommerce'), $percentage_fee);
    }
}

function fee_ids() {
    return array(652, 645, 625);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! How can I buy you a coffee to say thank you?